# Queries on data.stackexchange.com return empty fields

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Many queries that I wrote or not, return blank fields, but not always. To reproduce the problem try to execute this request :
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90306/compare-size-and-growth-trends-for-stackoverflow-tags

You see, the resulset stay with empties values. You can see this problems with many others popular queries like :
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions

It's a known behavior ? How to fix it ?

Comment: What browser? What OS?

Answer (score 1):

The first query gave me this:

[image]

which looks fine. The blank cells in this case are a part of the query and used for display formatting. (The blank cells under "Change" are hardcoded to be blank in the query itself. It's the baseline value, so there is no change by definition.)

The second query executed fine for me.

Can you provide a bit more information? Screenshots of the results and the tags/userids you're using as inputs to those two queries when they fail would be helpful.

Comment: [That is a horrifying query.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1962707#1962707)